# Why am I getting a "; expected" error?

Tags: java

```
public class homework
{
    public static void intPow(int a, int b)
    {
        Math.pow(a,b);
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        intPow();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to learn how to create a method, but I keep getting 10 ; expected errors. I know this code isn't correct, but I can't seem to find how to create a method correctly. In this case I'm trying to create a method that returns a^b.

Comment: You don't pass to `intPow()` any parameter?

Comment: What line(s) do you get that error on? I see plenty of things wrong, but not a missing `;`.

Comment: I like how none of the 4 FGITW answers has mentioned the lack of `return` or output yet.

Comment: @Geobits no need of `return`, note that the methods are `void`.

Comment: No need of return, unless you actually want your method and your program to be useful.

Comment: What is the point of `Math.pow(a,b);` if you don't either assign it to a variable or return it from the function?

Comment: @scrappedcola, I don't know. I'm brand new to programming in general. I'm not aware of some of these rules/connections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass two `int` parameters into `intPow()`:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 5;
        intPow(a, b); //32
    }
```

Furthermore, you should probably return an `int` from `intPow()` so you can play with it later:

```
public static int intPow(int a, int b) { 
    return Math.pow(a, b);
}
```

Then in `main()`:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 5;
        int power = intPow(a, b); //32
        System.out.println(power);
    }
```

Comment: The result is not 32 since the return type of intPow() is void.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just curious, why do you have to specify the variables in both main and the method? Since it says (a, b) in the method, why doesn't that carry to intPow();?

Comment: Think of those as just placeholders - whatever you pass into `intPow()` we will just call `a` and `b` **inside** the function.

Comment: The parameters in the method are called formal parameters. They define what the values will be called inside the method. The parameters that are passed to the method are called actual parameters. They determine what the actual values will be when the method runs.

Comment: @user2770254 the method declares that it needs 2 parameters to work. If you call it and do not pass the variables as declared, it will generate a compilation error.

Comment: I'm digressing a bit, but why did you remove the "static" from the method? Not criticizing, just curious.

Comment: There is no reason for it to be static - there is nothing in `intPow()` that can only have one instance of its scoped object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class

Comment: It's generating an error since I changed double to int. Why is this?

Comment: First of all, make sure your return types match their assignments. You cannot call `double foo = bar()` if `bar` returns an `int`. You must either make `bar` return a double or declare `foo` as an `int`.

Comment: "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Oi, of course, careless overlook on my part. Go ahead and switch it back to static, my mistake! :) (See edit)

Answer (score 3):

pass `two` `int` values in `intPow();`

```
intPow(5,5);
```

And anyways the value would not be printed.

You need to use `System.out.println()` to print it.

Answer (score 3):

Change

`intPow();`

to

`intPow(2,3); // or any number`

Answer (score 2):

You declare `intPow` as a function that takes *two* parameters. But when you call it from main, you dont pass any. To fix this, change this line in main -

```
intPow();
```

to

```
intPow(1, 2);//or whatever other numbers you want.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class homework
    {
        public static int intPow(int a, int b)
        {
            return Math.pow(a,b);
        }


        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int a = 3;
            int b = 4;
            int result = intPow(a, b);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to create a method that returns a^b, the method should return a value. You probly need to convert to int though, because Math.pow works with doubles.

```
public static int intPow(int a, int b) {
    return (int) Math.pow(a,b);
}
```

then call it using two parameters for a and b:

```
int result = intPow( 2, 3 );
```